# Кнопка поверх изображения-ссылки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть картинка, которая является ссылкой. Нужно добавить поверх этой картинки кнопку так, чтобы ссылка-картинка не потеряла своей функциональности, а нажатие на кнопку не инициировало нажатие на ссылку.

```
<a href="#" class=""  target="_blank">
     <div class="kartinka" style="background-image: url('');">
           <нужно вставить кнопку сюда>
     </div>
</a>
```

Comment: <a href="#" class=""  target="_blank">
     <div class="kartinka" style="background-image: url('');">
           <object><a href="#" class=""  target="_blank"></object>
     </div>
</a>

Comment: Не совсем помогло, но натолкнуло на правильные мысли) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно помещать кнопку внутрь ссылки. Предлагаю вот такой вариант.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.picture{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:url(//i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg) no-repeat center/cover;
}
.picture__link{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
}
.picture__button{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
  z-index:2;
  background:none;
  border:1px solid;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <a href="#" class="picture__link"></a>
  <button class="picture__button">✕</button>
</div>
<div class="picture">
  <a href="#" class="picture__link"></a>
  <button class="picture__button">✕</button>
</div>
<div class="picture">
  <a href="#" class="picture__link"></a>
  <button class="picture__button">✕</button>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня есть галерея фотографий, которые являются ссылками, они расположены в несколько строк, по 3 штуки в строке. Кнопка должна отображаться на каждой картинке, справа сверху (кнопка будет отвечать за удаление фотографии из галереи). Поэтому position:absolute не подходит

Comment: @rokoman13 , подходит. Кнопка же позиционируется относительно блока с картинкой. Смотрите пример.